# Zend-crypt must be installed to use the ajax_entity_controller in zenstruck/form-bundle

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, composer-php

I'm setting up a legacy Symfony project on a new server.

I've done a fresh `composer install` and everything goes well until this:

```
[Exception]
zendframework/zend-crypt must be installed to use the ajax_entity_controller feature.
```

Which is weird, because I can see that `zendframework/zend-crypt` has definitely been installed. See:

[image: SSH screengrab]

I'm pretty sure the Deprecation notices in yellow are unrelated.

Here's the error on the front end, which suggest the error originates in `zenstruck/form-bundle` which gets installed at the same time.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'zendframework/zend-crypt must be installed to use the ajax_entity_controller feature.' in /home/XXXXXX/vendor/zenstruck/form-bundle/Zenstruck/Bundle/FormBundle/DependencyInjection/ZenstruckFormExtension.php:46
Stack trace:
#0 /home/XXXXXX/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(50): Zenstruck\Bundle\FormBundle\DependencyInjection\ZenstruckFormExtension->load(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#1 /home/XXXXXX/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(39): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#2 /home/XXXXXX/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php(117): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfiguratio in /home/XXXXXX/vendor/zenstruck/form-bundle/Zenstruck/Bundle/FormBundle/DependencyInjection/ZenstruckFormExtension.php on line 46
```

Any smart ideas?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? The given error message is not thrown by Composer itself, but by your framework

Answer (score 1):

As a first hint: check for any more recent packages to solve your problem. Both that formbundle and `zend-crypt` are more than five years old, and I don't want to know about security issues...

About your problem. As you can see in the [ZenstruckFormExtension](https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckFormBundle/blob/v1.5.1/DependencyInjection/ZenstruckFormExtension.php#L46) throwing that error, it checks for the existance of the class `Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher`. According to [GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt/blob/release-2.3.1/src/BlockCipher.php), this file is present at the expected place. Can you check for any autoloader problems, like: is that namespace present in the autoloader? Does your application work if you remove `clearCache` from the Composer script section and run it by hand afterwards?

Comment: Thanks Nico.  Really useful insight.  Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher appears to be in place as expected.  I've rebuilt the autoloader and that seems to function correctly.

As a workaround I've disabled the ajax_entity_controller in the config for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game on this one. I'm the author of `ZenstruckFormBundle` and I do have a branch that *fixes* this issue: https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckFormBundle/tree/compat-sf4. It moves the exception to the `AjaxEntityManager::getBlockCipher()` method so you need to override the `encriptString`/`decriptString` methods (oh man, look at those typos!).

Use with caution though, as others have said, this library may have security issues.